# Optimally fair load balancing/multiprocessor scheduling of periodic tasks

Tags: algorithm, language-agnostic, load-balancing, scheduling, resource-scheduling

I’ve been thinking about scheduling and load balancing algorithms, and I came up with a problem that I think is interesting.

There are N cages and M zookeepers. Each cage has a size S and a number of animals A. The frequency with which a cage must be cleaned is computed as some function of A / S (smaller cages with more animals get dirty faster). The difficulty of cleaning a cage is computed as some other function of A and S, the details of which are unimportant (the size of a cage contributes most of the difficulty, and the number of animals contributes a little). Once every three days, any cages that are due for cleaning are cleaned (“cleaning day”). Zookeepers are completely identical and interchangeable. Zookeepers need to do a similar amount of work each cleaning day, and to not have to do much more work than any other zookeeper. The duration of time that a cage takes to clean is not part of the problem (it's assumed that time is roughly reflected by difficulty, and that there is always enough time in the day for a zookeeper to complete their assigned tasks).

The scheduling algorithm must tell each zookeeper which cages to clean on each cleaning day, such that

- each cage is cleaned at its ideal frequency or as close as possible,
- assigning a minimal and roughly equal number of cleanings per
  zookeeper per cleaning day,
- and assuring as equal a workload as possible across all zookeepers
  (i.e., over a period of time, the aggregate difficulties of each zookeeper’s workload are as close to equal as possible, and cages are distributed among zookeepers with roughly 1/M probability).

I’m wondering what an approximation algorithm for such an optimization problem would look like. It bears a resemblance to several different classic examples of NP-hard scheduling/resource utilization problems; maybe it is reducible to one such problem and I’m just missing it. If we get rid of the frequency/periodicity of tasks element, it is similar to the classic [multiprocessor scheduling](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiprocessor_scheduling) or finite [bin packing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bin_packing_problem) problem.

Comment: You might find a better answer on a different SO website than here.

Comment: The problem is underspecified because there's no description of the right way to trade off the multiple objectives.

Answer (score 1):

Given that the objective is to equalize zookeeper effort, the more-or-less standard way to handle such tasks this is on-line greedy.

In this case, that amounts to this:

Maintain a tally of the effort each zookeeper has expended so far, initially zero.  On each cleaning day, tally up the needed cleaning jobs and use first-fit, best-fit, or random fit to assign jobs in a way that will tend to equalize the work sums.  I.e. for best fit assign he biggest job to the keeper farthest behind in work assigned so far. Repeat until all tasks are assigned.